# populate check boxes dynamically from text in java

Tags: java, user-interface, checkbox, populate

i am working on a project where i have to display a set of records then the user can select 1 or more of these records to move them to another set.

i think the most appropiate componenet to use is Checkboxes. my probelm is that i cant add the check boxes to the frame automatically while reading the file. i added a panel, and added the check box but it still doesnt appear after using paint, or updateUI.
this is my code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()), "UTF-8"));

        String line = reader.readLine();
        String text = "";
        while (line != null) {
            text += line;
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        ArrayList<String> records = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(text.split("")));

        for(String rec: records){
        resPanal.add(new JCheckBox(rec));      
         }
         resPanal.updateUI();
```

the number of records is not constant, so i need a way to add the components = to the number of records found.
i am open to other suggestions that can help other than check boxes

Comment: so initially you are seeing checkboxes, but the new added ones doesnt appear, correct?

Comment: @TerryStorm. No, initially the frame is empty, with just a panel, once the user uploads a text file, it should start populating the check boxes.

Comment: So u r sure ur panel is added to the frame?

Comment: Yeah,, i use netbeans gui builder, so i am sure i have a panel. Its there when i run the program.

Comment: several things to check for you : 1) `text.split("")` splits after every character, dont know if u want that... but probably more like after every word (`text.split(" ")`)?! 2) long time ago i last used swing, but aren't the components not visible by default? try `setVisible(true)` on the panel or checkboxes maybe? has the panel a layout attached? FlowLayout or something like that? Or try invoke a repaint. UpdateUI doesnt actual do anything repainting related (i think)

Comment: apparently `setVisible(true)` was the missing ingredient. i tried it in a small program and it worked, regardless of the panel layout :) ... it still didnt work when reading from a file. i will figure something out.. thanks a lot @TerryStorm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone interested: 
i tried what @TerryStorm suggested in a small program with only a button, and each time the button is clicked a box is added

```
 private void addCBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

    JCheckBox box=new JCheckBox("add");
    box.setVisible(true);
     jPanel1.add(box);
    jPanel1.updateUI();


}
```

Comment: as i already said : `updateUI()` doesnt do, what u probably expects! it is **not** for repainting purposes! (also : please make at least an upvote if my comment was helpful)

Comment: @Terry i dont think upvoting a comment is possible, write your answer and i will upvote it :) .. regarding the repaint, it doesnt work for me but`revalidate()`, thanks for ur help :D